# Child component won't re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react with redux and I have a todo-list.
I have a 'Todos' component which acts like a container and a 'Todoitem' component which holds every todo.
Everything works fine - reducers change the state and it is updating with new data, but the child component (aka 'Todoitem' component) won't re-render.

Todos.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Todos">
        <div className="todos_title"> {this.props.title} </div>
        {this.props.todos.map(todo => {
          console.log(todo); // this line prints updated data from state just fine!
          return <TodoItem todo={todo} key={todo.id}></TodoItem>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// PropTypes
Todos.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todosReducer.todos
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos);
```

TodoItem.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { checkTodo } from "../actions/todosAction";

class TodoItem extends Component {
  onChange = (e, id) => {
    console.log(this.props.todo.completed.toString()); // this also prints fine the updated data
    this.props.checkTodo(id); // dispatches an action to the reducer to toggle the todo.completed with the right todo.id
  };

  render() {
    console.log('rendering'); // this is the problem - this line calls only in the first rendering, but not when state changes
    let { id, title, completed } = this.props.todo;
    return (
      <div className={completed ? "TodoItemDone" : "TodoItem"}>
        <p>
          <input
            className="todo_cb"
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e, id)}
            checked={completed ? "checked" : ""}
          />
          {id}) {title}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// PropTypes
TodoItem.propTypes = {
  todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  checkTodo: todo => dispatch(checkTodo(todo))
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem);
```

I noticed that if I do pass a mapStateToProps in child comp it is re-rendering, like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  some_prop: state
});
```

I understand the if I use mapStateToProps in the child it re-renders but I don't need anything directly from the state in child, the parent does this.
It makes some sense but my todos are stored in an Array in the state and I am mapping over them as you see in the parent component, so I can't map a specific todo from this array to the component props (how could I distinguish each element in the array to map to the prop?).

I am very confused.
I read that component re-renders when state or his props change. Inside the child component the props do change because the parent re-renders and it iterates the todos again and return the  component with new props.
Maybe it's not the way to pass the todos to the components but I still don't understand how come the props changes and render() is not called.

Thank you very much!

Edit 1:

I connected the checkTodo action to the parent component and passed the function with props and it works just fine.
Still I don't understand why before the child component haven't re-rendered with the previous code...

Edit 2:

Actually I just lied, it does not work. I forgot to remove mapStateToProps which I said worked, so I am back to square one.

Edit 3:

Solved with by calling forceUpdate(). Still can't understand why it happened.

Comment: Can you provide the codepen?

Comment: @PeterN It is part of the text, for exmaple - 1) Take out the trash

Comment: @RonB, sorry yes of course

Comment: if `.forceUpdate` solves the issue it means you are mutating state so that's why component is not updated on its own. but without code it's rather impossible to say where root cause is.